# Spring TransactionSynchronizationManager isActualTransactionActive() and getCurrentTransactionName() confusion

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data

I am confused a bit with Spring's  [TranscationSynchronizationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) `isActualTransactionActive()` and  `getCurrentTransactionName()` methods.

Given a non-transactional service

```
@Service
public MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
   public void someMethod() {
     boolean isActive = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
     String name = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName();
   }

}
```

Here I see that `isActive` is `false`, which is correct, on the other side when calling `getCurrentTransactionName()` I see the transaction name (it prints `de.mycompany.service.MyServiceImpl.someMethod`).

So if there is no transaction, why there is a current transaction name? Shouldn't it be `null`?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code of
`PlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction()`, which calls
`AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.prepareTransactionStatus()`, which calls
`AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.prepareSynchronization()`

It seems that **the name of the current transaction definition is passed to `TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionName()` regardless of there being or not an actual transaction**.

Therefore, in cases where an actual transaction wasn't started (e.g. for propagation `NEVER` or `SUPPORTS`), the confusion mentioned by you can happen. The method might be better understood as *get current transaction definition name*

Comment: Note that transaction synchronization happens even without an active transaction. That's what opens and closes the DB connection (or gets / returns it to the conn pool) for you.

Comment: Without an active transaction, isn't DB connection opened/taken when first needed? And if that happens, transaction synchronization would close/return it at the end of the transaction?

Comment: Yes, I was backwards. DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection() opens the connection and if tx sync is active, it will save the connection until the tx is completes. The connection is opened only when needed.